# Can somebody explain where my mistake is in this JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

really confused because I have no errors but I can't see which bit of my code is producing this:

```
rock
scissors
"scissors wins"
```

I've done a console.log to see the results as they come out so I know this is the wrong part but I can't remember where that bit is in my code now.

Code is:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}

console.log(userChoice);
console.log(computerChoice);

var compare = function(choice1,choice2) {

  if (choice1 === choice2) {
    return "The result is a tie!";
  }

  if (choice1 === "paper"); 
  {
    if (choice2 === "rock")
    {
      return "paper wins";
    }
    else (choice2 === "scissors")
    {
      return "scissors wins";
    }
  }

  if (choice1 === "scissors");
  {
    if (choice2 === "rock")
    {
      return "rock wins";
    }
    else (choice2 === "paper")
    {
     return "scissors wins";
    }
  }

  if (choice1 === "rock");
  {
    if (choice2 === "scissors")
    {
      return "rock wins";
    }
    else (choice2 === "paper")
    {
      return "paper wins";
    }
  }
};


compare(userChoice,computerChoice);
```

Any idea which bit is doing it?

Cheers!

Comment: `if (choice1 === "paper");` <- IF's don't need semi-colons and you've done this in several places

Comment: What's your logic for `0.34` and `0.67`? That's not random.

Comment: @user2191572 you should submit that as an answer so you can get credit.

Comment: `Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1` you can use this code to get a random number between 1 and 3 to have specific condition for your `if`

Comment: @sb thanks! I've had high-ranking users throw a tiff at me because they felt questions like this should have been closed rather than answered so I am still learning when it is safe to post easy answers lol but I always like to help people out

Comment: 0.34 and 0.67 and everything else utilise the math.random() function it's so the computer choice is a random of rock, paper or scissors.

Comment: JSLint or JSHint is your friend.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. Will use that from now on!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (choice1 === "paper");
```

Because of the semicolon, the next block is always entered

```
{
    if (choice2 === "rock")
    {
        return "paper wins";
    }
```

Here you have `else` instead of `else if`, so it ignores the condition and returns "scissors wins"

```
    else (choice2 === "scissors")
    {
        return "scissors wins";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

IF's don't need semi-colons and you've done this in several places

```
if (choice1 === "paper"); // <--
```

Answer (score 0):

You put `;` after your `if`s, you shouldn't.

If you put a `;` then the `if`'s scope end after the condition, the remaining code is executed after, like it's just a scope definition.

```
if (choice1 === "paper");
```

should be

```
if (choice1 === "paper")
```